# Find most recent rows from one dataframe based on a second dataframe

Tags: r, datetime, time, posixct, date-math

I have two dataframes, `dfburg` and `dfpolice`. For each row in `dfburg` (a list of burglaries), I want to know what row in `dfpolice` (a list of police officer activities) was the most recent, and the row that occurred afterwards.

The end goal is to see for each burglary how close to the incident did an officer patrol the area, and after the burglary did they stick around and patrol some more.

So if a `dfburg` incident occurs 8/22 at 9am, I would want to pull ***two*** rows from `dfpolice`, the ones closest to 9am on 8/22, both before and after.

Thank you. I have datetime vars for both tables.

Here is dfpolice
[image]

Here is dfburg
[image]

So for each row in `dfburg`, there would be two rows of `dfpolice`, the one closest to it before and after, there will be duplicates.

Comment: Would you be able to provide an example of your data and what you have tried so far?

Comment: Sure @al-obrien, check the OP now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think an easy way to do this would be to combine the tables with something like `dplyr::bind_rows()`, and then create a before and after column that copy the police_id and fill up or down from there. This would require having a matching datetime column in each table, but that's easy enough.

```
# I took some liberties with column names, as I didn't see the tables before writing
dfpolice %>% 
  dplyr::bind_rows(dfburg) %>% 
  dplyr::arrange(dt) %>% 
  dplyr::select(burg_id, dt, police_id_before = police_id, police_id_after = police_id) %>% 
  tidyr::fill(police_id_before, .direction = 'down') %>% 
  tidyr::fill(police_id_after, .direction = 'up') %>% 
  dplyr::filter(complete.cases(.))
```

From there you can just reference the `dfpolice` and `dfburg` table for whatever information you want, as the resulting table is the burglary id, the date of the burglary, and the police id for the call immediately before and immediately after.

Comment: This looks good - however I am a little confused as to what var names map where. I made var RealDate (the datetime) in both dfburg and dfpolice. Once i bind, do I need to use df$var syntax? I am getting 0 obs resulting from this code: '''dfpolice2 = dfpolice %>% 
  dplyr::bind_rows(dfburg) %>% 
  dplyr::arrange(RealDate) %>% 
  dplyr::select(burg_id,RealDate , police_id_before = dfpolice$policeid, police_id_after = dfpolice$policeid) %>% 
  tidyr::fill(police_id_before, .direction = 'down') %>% 
  tidyr::fill(police_id_after, .direction = 'up') %>% 
  dplyr::filter(complete.cases(.))'''

Comment: Could you help me with the varnames in your code now that I posted the tables? Keeping in mind RealDate is the shared DT var. Thanks

Comment: I think I figured it out, however, how do I export the resulting table to a df?

Comment: Do you mean how would you convert it from a tibble to a data.frame object? If so, the function `as.data.frame()` could be added to the end of that pipeline, or used directly on the object, like `as.data.frame(dfpolice2)`